# Disattached an image using Rails Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure it out how can I dis attach an image from my active record storage.

Basically what I did so far is:

1. Installed Active Storage.
2. Place `has_one_attached :avatar` on my model.
3. Then on my form I placed the `f.file_field`:

   ```
   <%= image_tag(@contact.avatar) %>

   <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
   ```

Now I have this:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
```

Which is a remove button. When a user clicks on this it must disattach the file or avatar image I've selected and simply depends on gravatar instead after removal.

[image]

Here's how I display my avatar image on the frontend:

```
<%= image_tag contact.avatar.attached? ? contact.avatar : contact.gravatar, class: 'media-object', style: "width: 80px" %>
```

I was thinking on how to implement this feature? Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purge` like this

```
contact.avatar.purge
```

Check the [guid](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#removing-files) for more options